# Laravel Spark - Can I limit plan API calls per month and API calls per minute/hour?

Tags: php, laravel, throttling

I want to use Laravel Spark to create different licenses for an API. I want to limit the API calls per month and also per hour/minute. For example the Basic License will allow 10 000 monthly api calls but I also want to limit the API calls per hour/minute for the same account. Can this be done with laravel spark?

There is: throttle and rate_limit, but can I limit total number of API calls per month and also per hour/minute? For example: 10 000 total api calls per month and max 60 api calls per hour/minute?

According to the docs, I can limit access per minute/hour: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#rate-limiting

Something like this combines throttle with rate limit:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api', 'throttle:10|rate_limit,1')->group(function () {     
Route::get('/user', function () { // }); 
});
```

But my main question is how do I combine rate limiting per minute/hour with the monthly limit?

Comment: Create a middleware and check there when the last api request was made.

Comment: I was thinking about using the middleware, but how should I count the monthly calls? How would I know when the user used all  Should I store them in the database?

Comment: I figured this out, thank you. I will store the monthly api calls in Redis and I will use Laravel's default Throttle for limiting minute/hour API calls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the same documentation page:

> You may also combine this functionality with **dynamic rate limits**. For example, if your `User` model contains a `rate_limit` attribute, you may pass the name of the attribute to the `throttle` middleware so that it is used to calculate the maximum request count for authenticated users

So, given the above, you could add an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) on your `User` model that gets the rate limit value based on their current subscription plan:

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function getRateLimitAttribute()
    {
        // Get license if it's a model

        if ($license === 'basic') {
            return 10000;
        }

        // Return some default here
    }
}
```

You can then use your dynamic rate limit value like this:

```php
Route::middleware('auth:api', 'throttle:rate_limit,1')->group(function () {
    // Rate-limited routes
});
```

As for the monthly limit, you’ll need to keep a counter somewhere and check that on each request. You could log each API request in another middleware:

```php
class LogRequest
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request);
    }

    public function terminate($request, $response)
    {
        LogRequestJob::dispatch($request);
    }
}
```

```php
class LogRequestJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        // Insert row for user to log request
        RequestLog::create([
            'user_id' => $this->request->user()->getKey(),
            'path' => $this->request->path(),
            // Store any other request data you're interested in
        ]);
    }
}
```

You’ll then need to check the count before handling a request, again using middleware:

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\TooManyRequestsHttpException;

class CheckRequestInLimit
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $year = Carbon::now()->year;
        $month = Carbon::now()->month;
        $count = RequestLog::user($request->user())->year($year)->month($month)->count();
        $limit = $request->user()->monthly_limit; // another accessor

        if ($count < $limit) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        // Count is equal to (or greater than) limit; throw exception
        $retryAfter = Carbon::today()->addMonth()->startOfMonth();
        $message = 'You have exceeded your monthly limit';

        throw new TooManyRequestsHttpException($retryAfter, $message);
    }
}
```

Hopefully this gives you food for thought!

**Edit on November 1, 2021:** This answer was written against an old version of Laravel. Laravel later introduced [rate limiting](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#rate-limiting) that would provide a more succinct solution to the problem above:

```php
RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
    return [
        Limit::perHour(60)->by($request->user()->getKey()),
        Limit::perDay(10000, 30)->by($request->user()->getKey()),
    ];
});
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the monthly api rate limiting solution. Can I combine it with an hour/minute rate limit? To have: 60 calls per hour and 10 000 cals per month? Could multiple rate limits be added?

Comment: I figured this out, thank you. I will store the monthly api calls in Redis and I will use Laravel's default Throttle for limiting minute/hour API calls.